# First node reassigned new data is read in

Tags: c, linked-list

I have created a `linked list`, now I am trying to read data in from a file however every time a new entry is read and assigned to the structure the first node is reassigned and removes the data from the previous entry. I would like to find out why my code is doing this.

```c
/* read file containing database of employees */
static void read_employee_database(char *file_name)
{
    char Name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH] = "\0";
    int Age;
    char Sex;
    char Job[MAX_JOB_LENGTH] = "\0";
    char ptr[10];
    char temp[100];
    int test = 0, count = 0;
    /*assigns enough memory*/
    Employee *pNewStruct = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));



    FILE *pFile;    

    pFile = fopen(file_name, "r");
    while (feof(pFile) == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nFirst node name %s\n\n", pFirstNode->name);


        read_string(pFile, "Name: ", Name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
        strcpy(pNewStruct->name, Name);
        read_string(pFile, "Sex: ", temp, 4);
        Sex = temp[0];
        pNewStruct->sex = Sex;
        read_string(pFile, "Age: ", temp, 100);
        Age = atoi(temp);
        pNewStruct->age = Age;
        read_string(pFile, "Job: ", Job, MAX_JOB_LENGTH);
        strcpy(pNewStruct->job, Job);

        fprintf(stderr, "The name is: %s \n", Name);
        fprintf(stderr, "The Age is: %i \n", Age);
        fprintf(stderr, "The Sex is: %c \n", Sex);
        fprintf(stderr, "The Job is: %s \n", Job);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");

        fgetc(pFile);
        /*Test all data for given entry*/
        test = checkName(&pNewStruct->name);
        if (test == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Name is issue");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (pNewStruct->sex != 'M' && pNewStruct->sex != 'F') {
            fprintf(stderr, "Sex is issue");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (pNewStruct->age <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Age is issue");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (strlen(pNewStruct->job) == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Job is issue");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else {

            if (pFirstNode->name == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "a new node is created\n\n");
                pNewStruct->next = NULL;
                pNewStruct->prev = NULL;
                pFirstNode = pNewStruct;
            }
            else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Else statement run\n\n");
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(pFile);
}
```

At this point in the code I only expect that the first node will be assigned given "`pFirstNode`" is a `public variable` that is `NULL`. However the newest entry that is read in automatically is set as `pFirstNode` even though the `if` statement condition is not met.

The Actual output:

```
First node name (null)

The name is: Graham, Billy
The Age is: 63
The Sex is: M
The Job is: Evangelist

a new node is created


First node name Graham, Billy

The name is: Karula, Roger
The Age is: 23
The Sex is: M
The Job is: Engineer

Else statement run


First node name Karula, Roger

The name is: Smart, Lisa
The Age is: 18
The Sex is: F
The Job is: Trainee engineer

Else statement run
```

I am using Ubuntu if that is important.

Comment: Read [**Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First node reassigned new data is read in

you allocate only one *Employee*, so you rewrite all the time in it, you need a to allocate one for each cell

```
Employee *pNewStruct = (Employee *)malloc(sizeof(Employee));
```

must be moved in the *while*, for instance just after

```
read_string(pFile, "Name: ", Name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH);
```

You will add the cells at the end of the list to respect the order, for that add a var pointing to the last cell (e.g. *pLastCell*)

In

> ```
>        if (pFirstNode->name == NULL) {
>            fprintf(stderr, "a new node is created\n\n");
>            pNewStruct->next = NULL;
>            pNewStruct->prev = NULL;
>            pFirstNode = pNewStruct;
>        }
> ```

add `pLastCell = pNewStruct;`

In

> ```
>         else {
>            fprintf(stderr, "Else statement run\n\n");
>        }
> ```

you need to link the other cells :

```
  pLastCell->next = pNewStruct;
  pNewStruct->prev = pLastCell;
  pLastCell = pNewStruct;
  pNewStruct->next = NULL;
```

---

Do not use *feof*, detect the end of the file in `read_string`, also manage the case where the file is invalid and some fields are missing

For instance :

```
while (read_string(pFile, "Name: ", Name, MAX_NAME_LENGTH))
```

and `read_string` returns 0 on EOF/error

Remove `fprintf(stderr, "\nFirst node name %s\n\n", pFirstNode->name);` it has no sense